# How can i get the vector register information in RVV0.7.1 when debugging with QEMU6.2?

Tags: vectorization, qemu, riscv

QEMU6.2 supports RISC-V vector extention0.7.1, and also I got riscv-gnu-toolchain for RVV0.7.1. When debugging, however, I can't get the vector registers using the command `info reg vector` or `info reg v1`.
Is there a way for me to get the vector information?

Answer (score 0):

You need a newer QEMU -- the support for reporting the vector registers via the gdbstub looks like it wasn't added until QEMU 7.0 (and there may have been some other bug fixes after that).

(In general, with a new and fast-moving target architecture like RISC-V, you're likely to have better luck using as new a version of QEMU as you reasonably can, and definitely when you run into something that seems like a bug or a missing feature it's worth checking whether a newer QEMU has fixed it.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Using the latest version of QEMU, I can get the vector registers when debuging. However, QEMU no longer supports RVV1.0 since QEMU7.0, so if I have a RVV0.7.1 specific executable, I have to use older version of QEMU.

Comment: In that case I'm afraid you're probably out of luck -- it sounds like there is no QEMU version which supports both exposing the vector registers via gdbstub and also the old vector extension spec.